# JAVA - Display data in Text Fields on a Form

Tags: java, database, user-interface

I am trying to build a library management desktop app by netbeans.

I succeeded in connecting database and adding new book and member information in database table.

Now I have tried to search information by id in table that is unique and want to show related information somewhere, such as in a Label or in a Text Field but I don't know the coding for that.

I have learned simple core java and before it a use discretionary and list to Store my infomation but in database connection how can I use if else clause ex.:

```
if(list-name.contains (book id))
{
     system.out.println("the book id already registered.");
}
else
{
      system.out.println("tthis book id is available.");
}
```

How can I write such as expression for database tables?

Comment: Please provide a final question matching with your needs, such as "how to display it on a screen ? " or  "how to get data from database?"

Comment: Thankz for ur time really. Going try this

Comment: It's working. Thank uh so much again . Another question in my mind is that I want a jtanlbe that show all data from database table. I've tried this by using jtable biding prosperity <biding source<import data from<mydatatablename. But it gives an error shows biding expreasion can't be null. Plese help

Comment: maybe it is a good idea to post another question on Stack Overflow. If the answer below helped you, please mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: How??  Can't find how to mark it as accepted

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. See more at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to read jdbc connection, and then take this demo example to raed out it helpful for you

```
    try{
    Connection con1;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con1=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.101.1:3306/dbname","username","password");
    PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement)con1.prepareStatement("SELECT * from tablename where columnname=valueofid");
    String str;
    ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();

    while(rs1.next()){
        int id=rs1.getInt("ID");
        String bookname=rs1.getString("clnmae1");
    String bookauthor=rs1.getString("clname2");

    //// there you can use label settext() method where to show your data
        }
       con1.close();

    } catch(Exception ex){
        out.print(ex);
}
```